# Installing freeglut3-dev on Ubuntu 12.04.4

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, software-installation, cuda

I'm a fairly new Ubuntu user and have been trying to get the CUDA toolkit installed for a project. I've been following this guide: http://pastebin.com/fDpqvSi5 to try and get it installed correctly, but I keep running into an issue when trying to install "freeglut3-dev". I have followed the guide I linked on a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install up to installing the libraries needed for the CUDA samples.

I tried using:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

but get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 freeglut3-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev or
                          libgl-dev
                 Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                          libglu-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try and install libgl1-mesa-dev or libglu1-mesa-dev a seemingly endless chain of dependencies is required which creates more dependencies for freeglut3-dev as well. The guide I am following is for Ubuntu 12.04.3, would there have been a change which means I need to do something different now?

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure if this has anything relevant to do with your situation but figured I'd contribute a direction to pursue anyway, since your question has no other hits yet.

I just installed 12.04.4 fresh (no upgrade from previous version) and had no problem installing freeglut3-dev with apt-get, as you've tried unsuccessfully. You say in your OP that you follow directions for installing on a fresh ubuntu 12.04.3 install, but don't specify whether you have a fresh install yourself, or have upgraded from an older release.

That said, since my fresh install I have installed a range of related libraries as I'm also in the process of getting CUDA running. Perhaps something I did triggered a series of packages to be installed that resolved this issue in a proactive way. I did break and fix ubuntu-desktop, unity, and compiz a few times in the process, so a lot has happened.

However, in my tinkering the following linked information turned up in finding out exactly what the differences are in 12.04.4 from previous 12.04 releases. It relates to some optional components you may or may not have in your current install depending on how you arrived at 12.04.**4**

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/ubuntu-12-04-4-released-new-kernel

Not sure if it'll help, or hinder, but worth a read-through anyway.

EDIT: Additional information might be found here https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa in the first few paragraphs. This is predominantly related to a ppa source for the most recent nvidia drivers, as opposed to installing from .run packages, but contains some other potentially relevant information.

In summary, I wonder if perhaps your problem is related to the fact that fresh installs of 12.04.4 have Precise X backport stacks, which I understand is an optional component of upgrading to 12.04.4 from an older release, as discussed in the first link I posted.

In other words, perhaps your issue is related to kernel version vs. mesa version. Maybe try a better package manager such as synaptic to see what version of these mesa packages is being fed to your system, upon which freeglut3-dev is dependent. My mesa packages are 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7, and am running kernel 3.11.0-17-generic.