# can't rum cmake or ompl gui

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and the last released library 1.0.0.
I'm a beginner.

**First I can't install `freeglut3-dev`.**

I tried to solve it from the other question
[Installing freeglut3-dev on Ubuntu 12.04.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423928/installing-freeglut3-dev-on-ubuntu-12-04-4) but it doesn't work. Please don't mark it duplicated.

This error appears with 2 dependencies. I INSTALL them but doesn't work.

```
some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

**Second** (I think the cause of the second one is the first one:

When I tried to install the ompl library, the cmake compile step after writing make it  comes with this error:

```
[ 92%] Building CXX object src/omplapp/CMakeFiles/ompl_app.dir/graphics/detail/assimpGUtil.cpp.o
/home/obuntu/omplapp/src/omplapp/graphics/detail/assimpGUtil.cpp:18:19: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GL/gl.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/omplapp/CMakeFiles/ompl_app.dir/graphics/detail/assimpGUtil.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/omplapp/CMakeFiles/ompl_app.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: possibly [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1428972)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124845/eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-generated-breaks-this-may-be-caused-by-hel)